# Is there a way to include a json file in my MAUI app that i can read and write to

Tags: json, maui, read-write

I've tried googling this without much success. I am trying to build a MAUI app where I can include JSONS of relevant objects that should be loaded into the app, and I can do this with bundling them in as MAUI assets, but for situations where I want to say:

Character Object>>>Add AssetObject to character.

Then read the updated character information into a json file to save for further use, i cant seem to find a way that works in a platform independent way. Any help?

I tried walking up through the directories using System.Reflection and System.IO, but that only works in windows, at least from what I saw.

Comment: files included in the app bundler are read-only.  You will need to copy the file to a user writable folder at startup in order to write to it.